# Excel CountIf & Sumif Substitution for linked closed workbooks

Tags: excel

Been struggling to find a work around for a countif & Sumif function to calculate across closed workbooks.

**CountIfs:**

FORMULA

```
=COUNTIFS('[Industrial - Feb.xlsx]Sheet1'!$I:$I,"<"&TODAY(),'[Industrial - Feb.xlsx]Sheet1'!$M:$M,{"To Do";"Preparing"})
```

DATA:

[image]

**Sumifs**

FORMULA:

```
=SUMIFS('[6401C30006715.xlsx]SAPUI5 Export'!$G:$G,'[6401C30006715.xlsx]SAPUI5 Export'!$A:$A,">="&C$2,'[6401C30006715.xlsx]SAPUI5 Export'!$A:$A,"<="&EOMONTH(C$2,0),'[6401C30006715.xlsx]SAPUI5 Export'!$D:$D,"="&$B4)
```

DATA:

[image]

Would greatly appreciate any assistance

Comment: What do you mean by a workaround? what is the problem, exactly? This kind of looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me

Comment: Sumifs and countifs give a #value error when pulling from closed linked workbooks, I need the figures to update even when the linked workbooks are closed